# Probate: Larke vs Nugus statement

Tags: united-kingdom, wills

When contesting a will in UK law a "larke vs nugus" letter may be sent to a solicitor holding the will to request they provide evidence relating to the how the will was drafted.
See for example:

https://www.wrighthassall.co.uk/knowledge/legal-articles/2013/04/09/how-start-disputing-will/

**Do you have to be a legal professional to request a Larke vs Nugus statement?
Can you request one only if you are contesting the will or is the possibility that you might sufficient?**

On the first point I have confirmed that a para-legal is able to do it which suggests that a layman might as well.

Not the main question but bonus points if you can provide insight into how this relates to client confidentiality?

Comment: The last question is very broad and additional to the rest of it. I suggest taking it out to be asked separately.

Comment: Agreed. I've weakened rather than removing it completely.

Comment: I have a related question here as well - http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16828/why-dont-nearest-relatives-have-an-automatic-right-to-view-a-will

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the solicitor who holds the will may give a Larke v Nugus statement to anyone he wishes. This wouldn't (or at least shouldn't) breach any rules of client confidentiality

That said, it is up to the discretion of the solicitor on who he gives such a statement to, and it is entirely possible (as was the case in Larke v Nugus) that the solicitor refuses to give such a statement, though as was pointed out in the article you linked, the Law Society has included in their guidelines that a lawyer should act in such a way as to avoid unnecessary legal costs in relation to probate, which should make it easier for someone seeking such a statement.

But I would believe that a lawyer would give out such a statement only to people he deemed should be allowed to access such information, which would generally be [people who could challenge a will](http://www.tmsolicitors.co.uk/about-us/contesting-a-will/who-can-contest-a-will/), including:

- Family Members
- Someone who was financially dependant on the Deceased
- A beneficiary under the will or an earlier will
- Someone who is owed Money / debt claims
- Someone who was promised something by the Deceased
- Someone who wants to obtain the grant of probate or letters of administration

For more information, [this](https://www.gov.uk/search-will-probate) is a resource that allows you to search wills and letters of administration for persons deceased after 1858

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on you providing legal services for yourself in the same way that there is no restriction on you performing an appendectomy on yourself. However, neither is a good idea for essentially the same reason: you don't know what you're doing and the consequences of screwing it up can be severe.